# Lock responsive image at the same position while resizing browser

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm trying to recreate a page like this website: http://www.ouiwill.com/#/about

You can see that the first image on the right stays at the same position as resizing the browser. To be more specific, the upper part of the image stays a bit on top of black background while the entire image sticks to the right edge of the browser all the time.) Well, on that website, that image actually moves to the bottom as the browser becomes very small. I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve that using CSS only, so I just want my image stays at the right edge and a bit on top of my yellow background at all time.

Here's my effort to achieve that: 
https://codepen.io/jennycysun/pen/BwOwve?editors=1100

Although my image is responsive, the position changes as resizing the browser. How do I make it stay at the same position?

```css
body {
  background-color: #FDEA6C;
}

#header {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  float: left;
  padding: 22px 90px;
}

h1 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none
}

h1 a:hover {
  color: #D3D3D3;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-bar ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 0px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav-bar ul li a:hover {
  color: #D3D3D3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.quote {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Cardo';
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 90px;
}


/*code below is relevant to the question*/

.about {
  color: DarkGray;
  font-family: 'Cardo';
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.profile img {
  width: 55%;
  margin-left: 84%;
  margin-top: -350px;
}

.about-bg {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9f2ccdb03b.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="header"><a href="./home.html">text</a></h1>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="./short-film.html">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <p class="quote">"text<br/> text text"</p>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div class="about-bg">
    <div class="about">

      <p class="about">text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
      <div class="profile"><img src="http://www.jacquelynclark.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/LargeScaleFloralArtandModernLamp-StudioMcGee.jpg"></div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>

    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

</body>

</html>
```

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Stablize your code by removing the `<br>` tags and using css styles, instead, to create spacing.

Looking at your code, I'm seeing that you're using a lot of `<br>` tags to create vertical space between some of your elements. This is not good practice.

Instead, you should add padding to your `<div>` elements, or margin to your `<p>` elements to create those separations. By removing the `<br>` tags, you make your html easier to read and it will be easier to predict what the browser will do with your other elements.

### For responsive design, try media queries with the new grid layout

If you want to create a responsive design, I'd suggest checking out the [new grid layout system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txZq7Laz7_4&t=1406s) and [media queries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KL-z9A56SQ).